# Cannot pop() more than once from the static stack

Tags: java, android, stack

I need to use a static stack in one of my android application.
Here's how i used it:

In the Constants File:

```
public static Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
```

And in the Activity File, inside the onBackPressed method following logic is used:

```
if (!Constants.st.isEmpty()) {
    Log.i("CHECK", "Stack is not empty.");
    Log.v("CHECK", "PEEK: " + Constants.st.peek()); 
    Constants.st.pop();
    if(Constants.st.isEmpty()){
        Log.i("CHECK", "Stack is empty.");
    }else{
        Log.v("CHECK", "PEEK after POP: " + Constants.st.peek());
    }
}else{
    Log.i("CHECK", "Stack is empty.");
}
```

Now when i press back button once it works (i mean pop() function works), then second time it( pop() function ) doesn't.
Here is the Log of the above logic:

```
: Stack is not empty.
: PEEK: UI_FirstActivity
: Stack is empty.
: Stack is not empty.
: PEEK: UI_SecondActivity
: PEEK after POP: UI_FirstActivity
: Stack is not empty.
: PEEK: UI_FirstActivity
: PEEK after POP: UI_FirstActivity
```

PS: Another thing is that whenever all these UI.. functions contains different dynamically created forms shown on the same activity. Now when we enter/show any method/form its name i.e., UI.. is been pushed in the stack.

PPS: I am fine with downvote, but a simple explanation will be very helpful.

PPPS: It seems that **EJB** is assuming that i am assuming :-). 
I will again try to explain what exactly is happening: 
I have an **activity** in which i am choosing to show various forms but one at a time.
each method UI_First... represents one form. now what happens is that sometimes one of the form is skipped from showing because it contains no views for example UI_Second... So after UI_First... UI_Third form is shown. Now when the user presses the back button ideal situation is that program will skip the UI_Second.. (because it contains no views) and open UI_First... To implement this functionality i used a stack where whenever a form is shown i.e., when UI_First... method is called its name is pushed in the stack. and when back button is pressed it is popped. I apologize if i was not clear enough.

PPPPS: i got the problem 10 mins ago. it was exactly was **pratik** is saying in the answer so i am going to accept his answer.

Comment: You never seem to push anything, so it's surprising that you can pop anything at all. Obviously when you go to pop the second time, there is nothing on the stack. Your code being incomplete, further comment is impossible.

Comment: @EJP i have already updated the push part.

Comment: There is no 'push' in the code you have posted.

Comment: @EJP please read the question. especially PS part.

Comment: Please read the part of the code that does a push and tell me where it is. I can't see it. I can only see your *assumption* that something is being pushed. ***Obviously*** that assumption is wrong: the question is, why? And that can only be answered by inspecting your precious secret code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any other thread which is simultaneously pushing strings onto the stack. Initially there was just one string 'UI_FirstActivity' which you popped. Around the same time some thread is pushing new Strings. So when you performed the second pop the other thread must have pushed the same string again

Comment: i am editing the question to clarify this. thanks.

Comment: I added a check(if the value is already present in the stack) before push. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is working fine. Here is what i understood, during first back press you have,

```
[UI_FirstActivity] alone and it pops making the stack empty.
```

But On second time you have,

```
[UI_SecondActivity,UI_FirstActivity] so it pops UI_SecondActivity alone you have 1 item in stack still.
```

Correct me if i misunderstood your question.

Comment: ya but after second backpress, it should pop UI_FirstActivity which it doesn't.